# Form that change input fields based on the input value selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I need to develop a web form where user select a category and based  the category new input fields appears. I know this has something to do with javascript. I looked into github and stackoverflow. But could not find a proper answer.

My requirement in simple way

## transacton form

1)Select Field: `domain, merchandise, vehicle`

2Select role: `buyer . / seller`,

3)Enter other pary email:

4) who pays escrow: `buyer, seller, both`

5) length of inspection: `1-30 days`

6) transaction title:

## 7) MERCHANDISE/VEHICLE ESCROW

```
ADD SHIPPING.
who pays for shipping
```

8)

## Domain ESCROW ( more than one escrow can add)

```
enter domain name

enter price
```

9)

## Merchandise ESCROW ( more item can add)

```
item name
quantity
 price
description
shipping fee
```

10)

## Vehicle ESCROW

```
vehicle year
vehicle make
 modal
price
```

User has the option to enter `VIN, odometer, notes, registration expiration date, state
titled, state registered,` and can include a `fee` for shipping.

```
shipping fee
```

As I mentioned when user selects `vehicle escrow`, the fields for the `vehicle escrow` needs to appear, I tried to do this using, **getElementById and innerHTML**, it seems quite complex.

Plus, certain fields need to add more than one time. I looked at **append** JQuery for this but still no clue.

I would be glad if anyone can help me with this regard.

Please do check the link below. It has a form where it changes according to the item selected.

http://ikman.lk/en/new

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please show the source code?

Answer (score 1):

You can  use below logic in this case. Also refer to below url to see how to show/ hide contents using jquery.

```
if( domain is selected){
  hideEveryThing();
  shopwSomeThing();  

}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 1):

So put all your top-level categories into a select element and then check for when one is selected with jQuery, then show that category's inputs (hide them all with CSS display: none first):

```
$('select').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == ' Category Name ') {
        show the inputs for this category;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using javascript then you can go with:

```
document.getElementById("divid").style.display="none"; //To hide div
document.getElementById("divid").style.display="block"; //To show div
```

If your using jquery then:

```
$("#divid").hide(); //To hide div
$("#divid").show(); //To show div
```

OR

```
$('#divid').css({'display':'none'});  //To hide div
$('#divid').css({'display':'block'}); //To show div
```